# Using subprocess with script using another version

Tags: python, subprocess

Can I use a script written in python 3.3 with the `subprocess` function to create a **pipe** between my script and another written in 2.7 ?

If the answer is yes should I be doing something like this?

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(['scriptInV2.7.py', '-arg1', '-arg2'])
myFunctionInV3.3(output)
```

I am pretty new to python, sorry for my lack of comprehension

Comment: So you just want the output of one passed to another? Also have you actually tried what you have suggested?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham is it possible to run two versions `Python2.x` and `Python3.x` parallel  on same machine ? Does that `Shabang` `#!` can do something here ?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I want to pass argument from one script in `Python3.3` to another script in `Python2.7` and recover the result in the first script (`Python3.3`).  I did not tried because I want to be sure that will be working before using this solution

Comment: Just try having the explicit path to the other Python you want to call before your script location, `subprocess.check_output(['C:/Path/To/PythonX.X/Python.exe', 'scriptInV2.7.py', '-arg1', '-arg2'])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your suggested approach. Either specify the python executable in the shebang (you need both python 2 and 3 installed in parallel):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2
```

and (in your python 3 calling script):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
```

*or* you can specify the interpreter when you are calling the script:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['/usr/bin/python2', 'scriptInV2.7.py', '-arg1', '-arg2'])
```

(update with the path to your python2 executable).

Comment: note: the shebang approach is more flexibly (it works even on Windows via Python launcher).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do so. However `check_output` normally takes an executable file as the first parameter, so `scriptInV2.7.py` needs to have execute permission set and have a shebang line that invokes python2.7.

You probably better explicitly specify the python executable as the first list element.